# Easily adding multiple existing users to a multisite site

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, user-registration, multisite-user-management

I manage a multisite network for a school. The sites are private (password protected), but users within the network should be allowed to access other sites as subscribers. (i.e. all students in a class should have subscriber access to the site of their classmates).

When you create a new site or new user, by default only the site admin has access to his site, other users are not added. You have to manually add other users as subscribers. This is ok when you have only a couple sites/users, but as soon as you have 10+ it starts taking a lot of time to add each user manually to each site.

I found many plugins, but they either seem to be very complicated with many roles configurations to do, or be simple but outdated.

This is basically a duplicate of this question: [How to add multiple existing users to a multisite site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200290/how-to-add-multiple-existing-users-to-a-multisite-site) but like I said, the plugin suggested here seems to be too outdated to use now.

I am basically looking for a plugin to allow me to select multiple existing users on the network when adding them as subscriber to a site, instead of having to type each user name manually and clicking "add".

Any easy way to do this? Or known "older" easy plugin known to work fine under newer WP versions?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. The way your questions is stated might be considered off-topic, as WordPress plugins recommendations or how to use them is considered [off-topic in this community](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is focused on development (specially WordPress core development). That said, 1) I suggest you edit and rephrase it to improve the odds of getting a useful answer. 2) The answer you pointed in the duplicate questions seems to point the two most viable and easy ways to deal with this challenge: hook to `user_register` and loop through each blog or WP-CLI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple existing users to a multisite site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200290/how-to-add-multiple-existing-users-to-a-multisite-site)

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server, [`wp user add-role`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/user/add-role/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. first, I'm sorry, since my search on google pointed me to the duplicate question and this was the most promising workaround I found, thought this would be the best place to ask. But unfortunately, since the plugins in this other thread are outdated and not maintained and seem to have issues with newest WP version, I can't really give them a try.